# Blur for different UIImages in same UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimage, uitapgesturerecognizer

So in my custom UITableViewCell I have 4 different UIImageView's & for each UILongTapGestureRecognizer.
[Table View Cells before adding images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJCrb.png)

After I add images and table looks like this :
[Table View Cells after adding images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkUeW.png)

I need to be able to delete image after long tap gesture recognizer, when the chosen image blurs out and remove button is shown.

I've added the long press gesture recognizer method and while I understand that I need to apply blur to the chosen image and not the UIImageView itself, I dont seem to get how to pass the reference of the picked image to the cell so that I can apply the blur filter to the image.
Is delegate legitimate to use in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply blur effect as you mentioned you need the image itself.
You can try something like this :)

```
UIImage *image = [yourImageView image];
UIImage *blurredImage = [UIImageEffects imageByApplyingBlurToImage:image withRadius:30 tintColor:tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:1.8 maskImage:nil];
yourImageView.image = blurredImage;
```

You can get UIImageEffects apple file from here :)
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UIImageEffects/Listings/UIImageEffects_main_m.html

Hope it helps :)